# curl cannot handshake https server created with Nodejs v14.16.0 tls.createSecureContext

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl

I have set up a HTTPS server (nodejs v14.16.0) and certificates from letsEncrypt (which work in the current version of the app that uses https.createServer). Unfortunately, curl cannot connect successfully to my HTTPS server. I get the following error

```
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Here's a minimum reproducible version of my server

```
const https = require('https')
const tls = require('tls');
const fs = require('fs');
const constants = require('constants');

tls.DEFAULT_ECDH_CURVE = "auto"
require('dotenv').config()

const certOpts = {
    key: `${process.env.KEY_PATH}/privkey.pem`,
    cert: `${process.env.KEY_PATH}/cert.pem`,
    ca: `${process.env.KEY_PATH}/chain.pem`,
};

  /**
   * 
   * @param {Record<string, string>} filePathMap
   * @returns {Record<string, Buffer>} 
   */
  function getBuffersFromFilePathMap(filePathMap) {
    const bufferMap = {}

    for (const path in filePathMap) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(filePathMap, path)) {
        bufferMap[path] = fs.readFileSync(filePathMap[path]);
      }
    }

    return bufferMap;
  }

const buffers = getBuffersFromFilePathMap(certOpts);


function createContext() {
    return tls.createSecureContext({
        ...buffers,
        secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
        maxVersion:'TLSv1.2'
    });
}

const server = https.createServer({ secureContext: createContext()  }, (req, res) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('connect');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('Hello World!\n');
    res.end('Goodbye World!\n');
  });

server.listen(9999, () => console.log('Server up: ', server.address()));
```

This is the output of `curl --version`

```
curl 7.61.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.61.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2k zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.6.2 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.4.2 nghttp2/1.31.1
Release-Date: 2018-09-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

From what I've gathered, ssl3 may not be supported .

Output from curl

```
$ curl -k https://localhost:9999
curl: (35) error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Curl traces

```
== Info: Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:9999/
== Info:   Trying 127.0.0.1...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9999 (#0)
== Info: ALPN, offering h2
== Info: ALPN, offering http/1.1
== Info: Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
== Info: successfully set certificate verify locations:
== Info:   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
== Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
=> Send SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
== Info: TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
=> Send SSL data, 512 bytes (0x200)
0000: .......*.c....}.5.H>^..e\;)}.zEW.....d....0.,.(.$.............k.
0040: j.i.h.9.8.7.6.........2...*.&.......=.5.../.+.'.#.............g.
0080: @.?.>.3.2.1.0.........E.D.C.B.1.-.).%.......<./...A.............
00c0: ............3.........localhost......................... .......
0100: ..............................3t.........h2.http/1.1............
0140: ................................................................
0180: ................................................................
01c0: ................................................................
== Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Unknown (21):
<= Recv SSL data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: .....
== Info: TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
<= Recv SSL data, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: .(
== Info: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: You set `requestCert:true, rejectUnauthorizhed:true` which tells the server to reject any client that doesn't authenticate with valid certificate and key. Your `curl` command does not authenticate (at all, much less validly) so it is rejected -- **exactly as you said you wanted**

Comment: even with those options set to false, I have the same handshake issues

Comment: `curl --trace-ascii blahblah.log` will dump a _lot_ of debug messages, incl. the details of TLS handshake.

Comment: I see it uses tls v1.2 but encounters an error. I'm going to edit the question with the curl trace since I cant post it in the comments as its too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it appears that even though the documentation for `tls.createSecureContext` says the result is "usable as an argument to several tls APIs, such as tls.createServer" it actually isn't. It *is* accepted by `server.addContext` (for a virtual host or more exactly an SNI-value handler) `tls.connect` (for client) `tls.createSecurePair` (deprecated) and `new TLSSocket` (low-level), but `createServer` only takes *the same options as* `createSecureContext` not an actual `SecureContext`. Since you didn't supply the needed key&cert in a usable form, and OpenSSL by default disables anonymous ciphersuites (which most clients don't offer anyway), all handshakes fail with no_shared_cipher. Try:

```
const server = https.createServer(
    {...buffers,
        secureOptions: constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
        maxVersion:'TLSv1.2' }, 
   (req, res) => stuff )
```

BTW the req,res=> function is invoked when you get a *request* not a connection as such; a proper client will only connect when it needs to do a request, but it is *possible* to connect without doing a request, and conversely fine to do multiple requests on one connection.

Comment: Thank you, the whole rationale for my using the tls.createSecureContext is so I can hotswap my keys when letsencrypt renews without restarting the server.
I can create an https server with the same keys (and buffers) using https.createServer. will I be able to hotswap my letsencrypt keys if i create the server via https.createServer and then call ```server.setSecureContext(tls.createSecureContext(...)); ``` @dave_thompson_085 ?

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer as it points to the core reason for the error.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/tls.html#tls_server_setsecurecontext_options
> server.setSecureContext(options)#
Added in: v11.0.0
options <Object> An object containing any of the possible properties from the tls.createSecureContext() options arguments (e.g. key, cert, ca, etc).
The server.setSecureContext() method replaces the secure context of an existing server. Existing connections to the server are not interrupted.